# Access google data using javascript - no solid information humans can understand

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have spent days trying to find any information or working samples on how I can get google data such as emails in my gmail inbox, list of my contacts, my calendar events etc...

None whatsoever :( There are broken pieces of some code fragments here and there, 90% say it's been deprecated, is the a one single page on the internet that gives me a working example how to do that from javascript. Many pages about oAuth, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it , I have spent days reading broken pieces here and there, but I was unable to understand what that it and how I can use it PRACTICALLY. Very sad, and I am very tired to waste so much time on things that dont work and are not documented in human language, possible to understand. Why do they have to overcomplicate thing so much and spread broken pieces of information everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit fragmented, but not that hard to get an overview of. Every Google API documentation page has a clear sign stating whether or not the API is deprecated or not.

Anyways, here's a [link to the Google Data Protocol](https://developers.google.com/gdata/) (with clear deprecation signs for deprecated APIs). If you follow that path, you should be able to navigate to the APIs that have replaced the old ones as well. I've personally been using the Gdata Python library to populate Google spreadsheets and it's working fine.

Comment: Everywhere I click there is a DEPRECATED message.

Comment: Besides, I could not find a single working example of how I can retrieve new gmail messages, nor how to use authentication for javascript requests.

Comment: I have used server-side libraries as well. I am talking about JAVASCRIPT only.